# Is there a way to check if the current Powershell script is being executed over a WinRM/PS Remoting session?

Tags: powershell

I have a case where I have some Powershell code to install software that is not supported to install over `WinRM`/`PS Remoting`. Is there a way I can check in the script whether it's currently executing in the context of a `WinRM` or `PS Remoting` session? I'm aware of how to check if a returned object came from a remote execution, but not how to check whether the current context is remote or not.

Comment: Are you trying to check being in the script which is getting executed remotely ?

Comment: Yes, I want to write a check in the script to bail if it's being run over Powershell Remoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `$PSSenderInfo` automatic variable which will be null in local sessions.